# Replace a certain value at a certain place in a text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

I want to code something that will replace a certain value, on a certain line, in a text file (thefile.txt). I've searched for a long time a solution to my problem but didn't found it. 
 Here is the code I wrote:

```
clist = [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
with open("thefile.txt", "w") as dataFile:
    for line in dataFile:
        (key, val1, val2 ,val3, val4, val5) = line.split()
        if key == clist[0]:                               #Find correct line
            line = line.replace(val1, clist[1])           #Replace the value I want, but not the others
```

My text file look like this:

```
1 0 0 0 13 0
2 9 4 5 2 3
3 0 0 4 0 0
```

For some reason, it doesn't work. I'm still a beginner at python, so I believe the problem might be with the fact that I tried to "read" the file in write mode (line.split). I don't know if line.split for each line is considered as reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help. In your example you are not writing the updated content back to the file.

**Demo:**

```
clist = [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
res = []
with open("thefile.txt") as dataFile:                    #Read file
    for line in dataFile:
        (key, val1, val2 ,val3, val4, val5) = line.split()
        if int(key) == clist[0]:                               #Find correct line
            res.append(line.replace(val1, str(clist[1])))      #Replace content and append to res
        else:
            res.append(line)

with open("thefile.txt", "w") as dataFile:                #Write back to file.
    for line in res:
        dataFile.write(line)
```

Comment: It didn't work, val1 isn't replaced by clist[1] in res

Comment: try: `if int(key) == clist[0]:` also use `res.append(line.replace(val1, str(clist[1])))`

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty output, right? And the original file probably is now empty too, right?

By opening the `dataFile` in `w` mode you are telling the system to open it for writing, and truncate it if it exists. When you later try to read it, the file have zero length because you just truncated it at opening time.

If you want to read a file, open it for reading. ("r" mode). If you need to update the file, open it for appeding data ("a" mode) or for update mode ("+" variants, so "w+" or "r+").

Anyways, if you have tu update the input file, you will have a hard time to do it properly as long as it's a text file (or a file with variable length records, in general). Your best approach is to write a new file fith the updated contents and replace the original file at the end, if required.

Answer (score 0):

In principle it is possible to update a textfile in place but that is tricky and error prone. What it requires is random access to the file and textfiles are not designed for random access.

Read your file in line-by line as you are doing (but set the mode to `'r'` for read), and write each line (modified or not) out to a new file that you open in mode `'w'` for write.